# how to pass **kwargs to a function from a class method

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I need to create a custom transformer class for a machine learning pipeline. The `testfun` is actually an R function accessed through rpy2. `testfun` is then used inside the `test` class. 
I want to expose all arguments of the R function represented by `testfun`, hence `**kwargs`. But I don't know how to pass `**kwargs`. Code below throws an error.

```
def testfun(x=1, a=1, b=1, c=1):
    return x**a, b**c

class test(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)
    def testkwargs(self):
        return testfun(**kwargs)
temp = test(x=1,a=1,b=2,c=3)
temp.testkwargs()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-131-de41ca28c280> in <module>
      5         return testfun(**kwargs)
      6 temp = test(x=1,a=1,b=2,c=3)
----> 7 temp.testkwargs()

<ipython-input-131-de41ca28c280> in testkwargs(self)
      3         self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)
      4     def testkwargs(self):
----> 5         return testfun(**kwargs)
      6 temp = test(x=1,a=1,b=2,c=3)
      7 temp.testkwargs()

NameError: name 'kwargs' is not defined
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: changes according to early suggestions didn't help much

```
class test(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)
    def testkwargs(self, **kwargs):
        return testfun(**kwargs)
temp = test(x=2,a=1,b=2,c=3)
temp.testkwargs()
```

Output:

```
 (1, 1)
```

Comment: The function `testkwargs` has no `kwargs` variable.

Comment: You need to add `**kwargs` to the `testkwargs` parameters: `def testkwargs(self, **kwargs):`

Comment: Why not store the `**kwargs` in `__init__` as `self.kwargs = kwargs` and then `return testfun(**self.kwargs)` from the `testkwargs` method?

Comment: `kwargs` isn't a single, named parameter (in the ordinary sense); it's a collection of keyword arguments to an individual method. It certainly isn't an attribute of the instance, and using `**kwargs` in one function isn't related to its use in another.

Comment: Agree with @SayandipDutta. Your call of ``__dict__.update()`` turns the entries of ``kwargs`` into attributes of your ``test`` instance. You could extract them later by calling ``testfun(self.x, self.y. self.a, self.b)`` (this assumes that ``x y a b`` are all set).

Comment: Why are you doing ``__dict__`` magic anyways? PEP 20: "Explicit is better than implicit."

Comment: it is not a strict object oriented application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you can do this way.

```
def testfun(x=1, a=1, b=1, c=1):
    return x**a, b**c

class test():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)
        self.kwargs = kwargs
    def testkwargs(self):
        return testfun(**self.kwargs)

temp = test(x=1,a=1,b=2,c=3)
temp.testkwargs()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test function should be like this..

```
def testfun(**kwargs):
    ... fetch each value using loop or similar...
```

Call testfun like that..

```
testfun(a=1,b=2...)
```

Comment: `{"a":1,"b":2...}` is not a keyword argument

Comment: @Farhan.K Edited my answer. Thanks